# How to open aspx page in flip mode or bit fancier?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

i am opening an aspx page in `gridview row command event handler` as pop up when we click link button

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "","window.open('YourPage.aspx');",true)
```

.All works fine but now i am thinking to open this aspx in flip mode just linke something rolling over and opens.How to do it??Do i need to use `jquerydialogue` and loads the page in it or any other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done this with jqueryui-dialogue